# After RAID failure SBS 2008 issues logging in and Exchange store does not mount

Tags: raid, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

today has been one of those days.

Yesterday a hard drive in our Dell Poweredge 2900 server failed and the RAID array didn't degrade gracefully, so I called Dell (Server still under warranty) and got an engineer to work though the RAID issues with me.

He was a nice guy but didn't do too much. We tried to put the RAID in a state where it was bootable and even though we only lost one disk there are still issues with the server.

Once we got the server to boot there was an error message saying that the logonui.exe was corrupted and we needed to run chkdsk. I clicked through the error messages and the login screen never came up. So I power cycled the server and it chkdsk automatically but the login screen didn't appear. I tried safe mode, no difference there either.

So the issues I am currently having are:
1) The server boots up, the loading windows screen comes up then it dumps me into a black screen where I can only see my mouse cursor. Ctrl+Esc doesn't work Ctrl+Alt+Del doesn't work
2) Some of the services come up: DHCP, DNS, DFS, and Print come up
3) The exchange information store and transport service don't start - I tried using mmc to connect to services.msc on the computer and start them but they throw an error message of "Can't start because group or dependency failed"

Has anyone had a problem like this? Can anyone offer some guidance?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What state is the RAID in now? have you rebuilt it with another disk? what RAID type is it?

Comment: It is a RAID 5 array, I haven't rebuilt it with a different disk yet. I figured it would be better to get the server running again before rebuilding it. If I should rebuild it first, just let me know